# Can we use Apache Shiro with angular 8

Tags: shiro

Can we use shiro with angular 8 based application. Currently we have spring thymeleaf based application with shiro. We are converting it to spring rest and angular based application. Now we need to include the authenication mechanishm for UI. Can we continue using shiro?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just render your login form with Angular instead of Thymeleaf.